# Fixed 64 bit integer in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

I want to have a fixed size integer of 64 bits in linux kernel.

My questions:

1. If I use `unsigned long`, then it may be 64-bit on one architecture and 32-bit on another. Right?
2. What would be the data type the for fixed
   64-bit integer?

I am specifically referring to linux kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use unsigned long, then it may be 64-bit on one architecture and 32-bit on another. Right?

Yes, the size of `unsigned long` is implementation-defined and therefore non-portable.

> What would be the data type the for fixed 64-bit integer?

`int64_t` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: In Linux kernel rather `u64`, `s64` or their ABI analogues `__u64` and `__s64`.

Answer (score 1):

The C language provides a lot of fixed width types, signed and unsigned.

As Lundin said, "the size of unsigned long is implementation-defined and therefore non-portable".

So, common types like `int`, `unsigned int` and `float` depends of your compiler.

You can see a full list of available fixed width integer types since C99 [in this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)

`int64_t` is, according to documentation, a "**signed** integer type with width of exactly 64 bits with no padding bits and using 2's complement for negative values".

`uint64_t`, also according to documentation, an "**unsigned** integer type with width of exactly 64 bits"

But there are more other fixed 64 bits width integer types you may be curious to see, as: `uint_fast64_t`, `uint_least64_t`

I recommend you to see the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) and have a lot of fun learning the magical C types \o/

You can also check the available types on the [GNU libc manual of integer types](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integers.html)

Hope this helps!